# How to solve the problem while loading package "ggtext" in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, visualization, ggtext

I want to use **ggtext** packgae  for visualization in R, but while I loaded the packgae that I have installed before I found this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggtext’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘ggplot2’ 3.1.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.3.0 is required
```

What might be the main problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: The message is basically saying that your ggplot2 installation is too old,first restart R and try install.packages() again on ggtext, if it fails let me know

Comment: Maybe I will try your advice Mr. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

That error helps... when it says: "namespace ‘ggplot2’ 3.1.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.3.0 is required" means that the version of ggtext you've installed needs ggplot2 to be upgraded (to at least 3.3.0) for it to work (it must use a newish feature in ggplot).

Fix: restart R, install.packages("ggplot2"), then try again (you may need to install.packages("ggtext") again).

Comment: That seems right. As a sidenote, the new feature ggtext is probably using is the updated theme element tree.

Comment: But when I checked the version of "ggplot2" package, it showed 3.3.2. It made me confused.